# In C, is there a way to get numa node info of network interface

Tags: c, linux, networking, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

In C, is there a way to query numa node info of network interface?

My system is ubuntu 14.04.

Right now, I can only get it via doing the following in bash:

cat /sys/class/net/[device_name]/device/numa_node

Thanks a lot,

Comment: This probably isn't ideal, but you could use the C file IO functions to read that file instead of using cat.

Comment: @SimpleJ sorry for the confusing description.  yeah, i was trying to avoid that

Comment: @SimpleJ also user may mount sysfs at different place,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the **libnuma** api which **numactl** uses.

http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/LibNUMA-WP-fv1.pdf

Though you might bee making more work for yourself as sysfs has already
organized this for you. In the kernel you can get the numa_node off struct device which is embedded in struct pci_dev. The sysfs accessor function is **numa_node_show**.

Comment: Thx for the link and the bit of history~!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think most of this kind of info is only in sysfs,......

I'll use C file IO functions to read it.

Thanks a lot @SimpleJ.